# Why doesn't click event trigger .submit()?

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, click

I am trying to send a form by using a click event to trigger the form submission. For some reason however, this does not seem to work.

Code:

```
<form id="send_intake">

    <div class="input_line">Voornaam: <input type="text" name="firstname" id="send_intake_firstname"></div>
    <div class="input_line">Achternaam: <input type="text" name="lastname" id="send_intake_lastname"></div>
    <div class="input_line">E-mailadres: <input type="email" name="email" id="send_intake_email"></div>

    <input type="submit" class="form_submit" value="Stuur">
</form>

<script>
//Send form
$(document).ready(function(){

    $(".function_header").on( "click", "#submit_send_intake", function() {
        alert ("click event fired.");
        $("#send_intake").submit(function() {
            $.post("pages/forms_intake/functions/send_intake_form.php", $("#send_intake").serialize());
        });

    });
});
</script>
```

Hope you guys can see what's going wrong here :(

UPDATE:

Sorry for not providing you with all the information.

Actually this form is part of a web app. The form is inside a .php file that is loaded into a dashboard with .load().

The situation is as follows:
In the dashboard file, there is a specific DIV in which forms are dynamically loaded upon user's request. But for UI reasons I want the users to be able to submit the form with the same button every time. So when the form is loaded, the ID #submit_send_intake is assigned to that button. I'm using Jquery event delegation to bind the click event to the dynamically added ID by specifying the buttons' parent element, which is .function_header.

To summarize: .function_header and #submit_send_intake are elements that exist in the parent document (dashboard) of this form document.

Comment: You should always give your form action and method attributes.

Comment: i do not see any element with a class of `function_header`, so your jquery selection `$('.function_header')` selects nothing and adds no event handler, also do not see an element with id `submit_send_intake`, are these somewhere else in your code that you are not showing?

Comment: I also see no element with the ID of `submit_send_intake`.

Comment: `$(".function_header").on( "click", ".form_submit", function() {` should work provided the class `function_header` exists and is the correct context.

Comment: Post updated. Sorry for not providing this essential information.

Answer (score -1):

1. I cannot see element with class function_header and element with ID submit_send_intake. Probably you didn't copy that part of markup (but please check).
2. If you leave action empty in your form tag, your page will be refreshed by submit. So you should specify action.

Comment: Way to find same mistakes as other people can find. It happens, isn't it? Maybe you will better add some valuable comment?